# How do I prove these three statements true/false?

Tags: prime-numbers

I am still being taught maths at school, so all these fancy symbols like $\sum$ I have no idea about (although writing it out through mathjax, I think it possibly means the "sum" of something) but I believe to have made three potential discoveries of always finding a prime number:

$1. \qquad (2n + 1)^2 - 2 = p$

$2. \qquad n^3 - (n - 1)^3 = p$

$3. \qquad \text{The first number after $(2n)^2$ to have the number $7$ as its last digit is always prime.}$

I do not know if these are facts, but I do not know how to prove if any of these are true or false.

---

**My Attempt:**

$$(a + b)^2 = (a + b)(a + b) = a^2 + ab + ba + b^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab \tag1$$
$$\implies (2n + 1)^2 = (2n)^2 + 1^2 + 2\times 2n\times 1 = 4n^2 + 4n + 1$$
$$\implies (2n + 1)^2 - 2 = 4n^2 + 4n + 1 - 2 = 4n^2 + 4n - 1= p$$
$$\implies 4n^2 + 4n - 1 - p = 4n^2 + 4n - (1 + p) = 0$$
$$\therefore n = \frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{16 - 16(1 + p)}}{8}$$
This is where I get stuck because any prime number must be greater than $1$ which implies that we will be square rooting a negative number in the numerator of the above fraction. Doing a little bit of research, the square root of a negative number is not "real" so how can there be real solutions for $n$ such that $(2n + 1)^2 - 2 = p?$ For example, $(2\times3 + 1)^2 - 2 = 47$ which is a prime number. I cannot see if I am doing something wrong here. Is this a contradiction of some sort?

$$(a - b)^3 = (a - b)(a - b)(a - b) = \cdots = a^3 - 3a^2b + 3ab^2 - b^3\tag2$$
$$\implies (n - 1)^3 = n^3 - 3\times n^2\times1 + 3\times n\times1^2 - 1^3 = n^3 - 3n^2 + 3n - 1$$
$$\implies n^3 - (n^3 - 3n^2 + 3n - 1) = n^3 - n^3 + 3n^2 - 3n + 1 = 3n^2 - 3n + 1 = p$$
$$\implies 3n^2 - 3n + (1 - p) = 0$$
$$\therefore n = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt {9 - 12(1 - p)}}{6}$$

Since $(1 - p) < 0$ then this implies that $12(1 - p) < 0$ and so we will be square rooting a *positive* number in the numerator of the above fraction because:
$$\forall (x, y) \in \mathbb{Z}, \ x - (-y) = x + y > 0 : x = 9\land 12\mid y$$
But I am unsure that I completed this problem correctly because I used the same steps of working out compared to $(1)$, however I cannot find a problem here. For example:
$$(\pm 3)^3 - 2^3 = 19 \qquad \text{ and } \qquad \pm 3 = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt {9 - 12(1 - 19)}}{6}$$

But as for $(3)$, I do not know where to begin. Could somebody please help me and show me step by step how to prove *any one* of these statements true or false? You do not have to prove *all* three statements true or false, but if you wish to do so, it would be much appreciated. I tried solving for $n$ via the *quadratic formula*, and *completing the square* just gave me a simplified fraction for $n$ and nothing more. If you are willing to use other mathematical techniques of solving for $n$, please be clear and try not to skip too many steps in the process. Thank you in advance.

---

**Edit:** Can I just say, this was my first question on the MSE and it said "be clear" and "be specific" and things like that, so I tried to make this question as understandable as possible, and for my first question, I got +10 which is AMAZING! Thank you so much all of you people for helping me with this. Your answers and explanations were very clear and helped me have a further understanding of these problems, and now I can use other methods of solving problems like these (or perhaps simply trial and error). I absolutely love this community even if some math questions are WAY beyond my years! Once again, thank you so much! :)

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that $(2n+1)^2-2$ is always prime?  But $11^2-2$ isn't.

Comment: A suggestion:  in testing forms like this, you need to look at a lot of examples, not just the first two or three.  There are a lot of small primes so if you only look at small numbers you get a distorted view of things.

Comment: Note:  it's not too hard to prove that there is no non-constant polynomial $p(n)$ with integer coefficients that only takes prime values.  Worth doing as an exercise.

Comment: @lulu Regarding the polynonial, $p: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, correct?

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek  Well, $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ will do.  It's a divisibility claim, not a statement about positivity.

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek  Historical trivia:  Pretty sure this was first shown by Goldbach.  In any case, it's old.  And it's worth mentioning Euler's example $n^2+n+41$ which gives primes for $n\in \{0,1,\cdots, 40\}$.

Comment: @lulu I'll give the problem you offered a shot. And thats interesting! I don't know much about Goldbach admittingly -- I'm currently reading through *Men of Mathematics* and don't believe he's included. Also, thats definitely a formula worth remembing, thanks for bringing it up. :)

Comment: For examples like the last one you can construct counterexamples as follows - since the final digit is controlled, take $n$ a multiple of $5$ so that $(2n)^2$ ends in a zero - then you know that "last digit $7$" means adding $7$. Then if $(2n)^2$ is a multiple of $7$ the sum will have a factor equal to $7$ and won't be prime. So $n$ a multiple of $35$ will provide counterexamples. This strategy of knowing some part of the result (like the last digit), identifying a divisor, and then controlling the bit you don't know about so that it shares the same divisor is useful to know.

Comment: any non-constant polynomial can't always be prime.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Lucky I'm not one of those guys that cannot take constructive criticism, but a mathematician must be prepared for feedback like this :)

Comment: To prove any of them false it suffices to find a single counter-example. For 1. take n=5 (or n=8). For 2. take n=6 (or n=9). For 3 take n=6 (or n=9).  There is no known simple formula for producing primes in spite of thousands of years of study.

Comment: I think your solutions of the quadratic equations are wrong. $4n^2 + 4n - 1= p$ is satisfied by $n=1$ and $p=7$ , but $n = \frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{16 - 16(1 + p)}}{8}$ isn't

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first proposition $n=5$ is a counterexample.
$$(2\cdot 5 +1)^2 -2 = 7 \cdot 17$$

For the second proposition, $n=6$ is a counterexample.
$$6^3-(6-1)^3=7\cdot 13$$

For the last proposition, $n=6$ is a counterexample.

$$(2\cdot 6)^2=144 \text { and } 147=3\cdot 7^2$$

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I must have overlooked that. I mean, $7\times17 = 119$ which looks like a prime number....yeah perhaps I need to test just a little bit more...

Comment: @user477343 Please see my edit for the remaining propositions.

Comment: Well, if you don't bound n>1, 2 can be contradicted with n=1.

Comment: Ok thank you for those.

Comment: @user477343 On the note of proving things like this though, I highly recommend reading up on a method of proof called *induction*. Good try though!

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek thanks for that. I will look into it :) And also, it seems like every counter example is divisible by 7.

Comment: @user477343 No divisible by $7$ is not necessary, for example for 1, $n=11$ gives $527=17\times 31$. For 2, $n=8$ gives $169=13^2$. For 3, $n=9$ gives $327=3\times 109$.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime I know $7$ wasn't necessary, I was just lazy. Turned on my calculator and put $f(x)=\frac{(2x + 1)^2 - 2}{7}$ then scrolled through the table to spot integers. Factors of $7$ are easy to overlook so figured its worth a shot. For the final proposition though, it just happened to have a factor of $7$.

Answer (score 4):

You can disprove such a statement by finding a counterexample.

- For small values of $n$ you can do this manually. There are at least 2 counterexamples for $n\le 10$ for each of your claims.
- Your claims are wrong for at least 50% of all $n\le100$. For larger $n$ these values increase. So if you select an arbitrary two digit number you have at least 50% chance to find a counterexample. You can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=477343+**3-(477343+-1)**3+prime%3F) to check if a number is a prime number.
- To check a larger range of values you can write a program, e.g. in Python or Mathematica.

Comment: Yes I have heard of Mathematica whilst browsing on this site, but thank you for this. How do they put it? "I give you a (+1)" :)

Answer (score 3):

Disproving by simple counterexample is the right approach.

In your (1), the quadratic formula result has a sign error.  It should be $\sqrt{16+16(1+p)}$, not $16-16(1+p)$.

Building solutions using the quadratic formula requires a lot of steps where there can be errors, so you should always test the result with a simple case, e.g. plug $n=1$ into (1), get $p=7$, and see if those values solve your quadratic.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Ok I will fix my error. Thank you. And by the way, even though you have not used mathjax, I still understand your comment so thank you. +1